# How do I keep OS X from requiring admin password when I copy to or delete from its web server?

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mavericks

I've started using the Apache web server that comes with OS X (10.9.4) for testing. When I copy files to its web root (/Library/WebServer/Documents) or delete from the same, I get prompted for the admin password. I have this password, so that's not a problem. It's just inefficient. I haven't had this issue when using other installs of Apache (generally via MAMP). So I'm sure it's just a config issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to protect the directory, you can add an ACL to allow your user account read/write access to that folder.

You can add the ACL as follows, Please be sure to change "yourshortname" to your username on the computer.

sudo chmod -R +a "yourshortname allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity" /Library/WebServer/Documents

[image: Finder Info]

Let me know if it works for you.